# Unable to set Tail Number on some aircraft

Tags: microsoft-flight-simulator

I've managed to 'permanently' change the Tail Number / Registration number across most of the aircraft in MSFS2020 by editing the `aircraft.cfg` files and changing the `atc_id` tag as advised in various posts online, but it seems a number of aircraft don't have an aircraft.cfg file.

The DA40-TDI is one example.

I have tried creating an `aircraft.cfg` file in the same place as this config files lives for other aircraft and have recreated what I believe is the relevent part of the file, but it's still not changing the Tail Number.

What I've created is:

```
;===================== FLTSIM =====================

[FLTSIM.0]
atc_id = "M-YTAIL" ; tail number
atc_id_enable = 1 ; enable tail number
atc_airline = "" ; airline name
atc_flight_number = "" ; flight number
```

This is being placed under the `official` folder rather than under the `community` folder - I might try the community folder at some point.

It has been suggested that the Premium aircraft don't have `aircraft.cfg` files as part of the copy protection, but I haven't been able to confirm that yet.

Has anyone managed to change the Tail Number on the DA40 or any of the others without `aircraft.cfg` files?

---

UPDATE

I've tried putting the new aircfraft.cfg in `Packages\Community\asobo-aircraft-da40-tdi\SimObjects\Airplanes\Asobo_DA40_TDI` but still no tail number change. I'll play around with the sub-folder structure, but it would be useful to know what the structure is for community aircraft.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that one of the recent updates (5, 6 or 7) has resolved this. I can now change tail number for all bundled aircraft (Premium Deluxe bundle) that I have tried, and the change persists between sessions.